# QTextDocument: How to remove a resource from cache

Tags: c++, qt, caching, resources, qtextdocument

My program is using several different `QTextBrowser`s to show contents to user. Some of these contents have images. which I load from file into `QPixmap`s and add them to the text document to show.

Suppose a code like this:

```
QTextBrowser* browser = new QTextBrowser(this);
//Codes to add the browser to GUI
QPixmap pix;
pix.load(file_address);

browser->document()->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource, QUrl("url://Test1"), pix);
browser->setHtml( "<img src='url://Test1' width=120 height=90 />" );
```

Later on, I no longer need the browser, so delete it:

```
browser->deleteLater();
```

Now my problem is: **how can I remove resources that were added to this deleted browser, from cache?**

`QTextDocument`'s [document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qtextdocument.html#addResource) mentions that:

> void QTextDocument::addResource(int type, const QUrl & name, const
>   QVariant & resource) Adds the resource *resource* to the resource cache,
>   using type and name as identifiers.

So, the resource remains in cache until I close the application. But I need to clear it beforehand, because there are lots of resources being added to the cache, and the app could be running for several days in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cached resources are attached to the `QTextDocument` instance (not a global cache), and will be freed when the document is destroyed, or when `QTextDocument::clear()` is called. You can see in the source code:

- [1](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextdocument.cpp.html#_ZNK13QTextDocument8resourceEiRK4QUrl): `QTextDocument::resource` calls `loadResource` to actually read the file contents.
- [2](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextdocument.cpp.html#_ZN13QTextDocument12loadResourceEiRK4QUrl): `loadResource` stores the resource contents in the `cachedResources` member

As this is a member of the private class associated with the `QTextDocument` instance, it will have the same lifetime.

Comment: That's correct and as I expected it to work. Apparently, I had a mistake in my evaluation code. it's now working as it should. Thanks.